# LNK2038, iterator mismatch error, need to ignore

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008, linker, iterator

I'm getting the linker error LNK2038 when trying to convert a VS2008 project to VS2010. This error occurs when two different projects are compiled in which one is using _DEBUG preprocessor macro, and the other is not. Basically I have a 3rd party library that only has release .libs, so when I try and use that library when building my project in debug mode I get this mismatch.

I understand why Microsoft is giving this error (STL iterator safety), however our project does not use Microsoft's STL, we use STLPort, so this error means nothing to our project. I just need a way to prevent it from doing this check.

Inside of the STL includes there is a file called yvals.h, which includes the #pragma detect_mismatch definition for the various _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL settings. That set of definitions is wrapped in an #ifndef _ALLOW_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL_MISMATCH, #endif. However, even if I define _ALLOW_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL_MISMATCH as a preprocessor macro for my entire project I'm still getting the same linker error. I can even alter yvals.h to define that macro and it does nothing (I'm assuming because the STL itself would need to be recompiled).

So my question is basically, what steps can I take make _ALLOW_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL_MISMATCH actually work as intended so that my project doesn't do this check anywhere when compiling in VS2010?

EDIT: I know this is a late response but I just found this post and realized I didn't post the solution. As others mentioned there was a mismatch in the libraries. As it turns out VS2010 changes the default directories for certain projects (I found a thread on MSDN at one point full of complaints about it), and that directory change had caused VS2010 to look in the wrong directory for the debug library, and it was finding the release library instead.

Comment: Your project and the 3rd party library are both going to link to the same version of the library containing the standard template implementation, so they *must* match. Trying to mix is only going to result in much pain, eliminating the warnings would only be the start of it.

Comment: They do match, they're both using the same version of STLPort, which is what we use for our STL implementation. We don't use MSFT STL in any case. In fact, I don't see why our project is referring to the MSFT STL to even get this error.

Comment: You say this is a 3rd party library - you're absolutely sure they're using STLPort too? Have you determined who's including yvals.h?

Comment: This 3rd party library is pure C, no STL use in it. I haven't determined who is using yvals.h yet, but I get the feeling I'm running into a dependency issue, which is outside of the scope of this thread/question.

Comment: A note that may help somebody: I had the same linker error, and defining _ALLOW_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL_MISMATCH as a preprocessor define **DID** fix the issue for me. I was trying to manually set the _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL and that was totally crashing, but allowing the mismatch pure and simple fixed it. Since it was a linker error, it didn't appear to be possible to ignore it. Hope this helps somebody!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use the same version of the standard library, compiled with the
same options, if you expect to successfully link.  If you use STLPort,
then you can only link with libraries which use the STLPort, not with
libraries which use the VC++ standard implementation.  If you mix,
either you will fail to link, or you will get strange runtime errors.

The problem is that things like `std::vector<>::iterator` may be defined
completely differently; depending on where and how they are used, you
will find yourself using an instance constructed in a different library, 
with a different layout.

Comment: We're using the same STLPort for all of our projects as we were using in VS2008, VS2010 doesn't change that whatsoever, the difference now is that VS2010 is doing this check for iterator mismatches when it doesn't need to. Basically the code for the project should be nearly identical in our VS2010 project as our VS2008 project, including our STL, so this check is worthless to us.

Comment: @Nic If it worked, it was purely by chance.  You can easily end up creating an iterator in a module compiled with the STLPort, and using it in a module compiled with the VC++ library.  Formally, mixing two different versions of the library is undefined behavior, and in practice, it will often give problems.