# How can I ignore LNK2038 (define mismatch)?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, linker-errors

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [LNK2038, iterator mismatch error, need to ignore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7572636/lnk2038-iterator-mismatch-error-need-to-ignore)

I have a third party static library, which is also statically linked with the C/C++ runtime. I only have a release build of this library.

When I attempt to link this library into a debug build of my applications, the linker complains that the iterator debug level of the static library (0) doesn't match the level of my application (2).

Is there any way to force the linker to ignore this error? I'd like to be able to use the functionality added by this library in debug mode, and obtaining a debug build of this library isn't possible.

As an aside, I can't immediately think of any problems that would arise from this define mismatch.

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: Could you post the exact error? This might well be an issue if you are talking about C++ standard library iterators in Visual C++ are very different implementation-wise between the debug and release versions.

Comment: You could create a new DLL which links in that static library and then dynamically link against your new DLL, but that'd be a huge pain.

Comment: @BoPersson: This isn't a duplicate. I understand what this error is and how to fix it, but the fix isn't possible for me. I'm asking how to force the linker to ignore this mismatch and continue linking.

Answer (score 5):

The standard says thing like "iterators are undefined after a change to the container".  Some debug mode STL will check for this error, while most release mode STL will not check.  There are extra member variables in the container or iterator classes in debug mode to implement these checks.

So mixing debug and release STL version will not work because the number of bytes in container or iterator classes can be different.  The same can happen for any class that has different member variables between debug and release mode.

Comment: I don't see why this would or could be an issue, because standard library containers and types are not passed across library boundaries and the third party library has it's own runtime statically linked.

Comment: Warning - lots of guessing here.  Say the 3rd party library uses std::vector<int> and your code uses std::vector<int> but that type is not used as an argument or return type for any function provided by the 3rd party library.  Most compilers try to minimize code bloat by only instantiating once version of a template.  So does your exe use the debug or release mode instantiation of std::vector<int> ?

Comment: This may not not answer your question, but hope it helps. Usually, you debug build have _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL set to 2, and the release build set it to 0. That caused LNK2038. If you want to mix the your debug build of application to the release build of library, you could add `#define _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL 0` to your codes. And it should work.